# Get DB stats (number of updates/deletes/inserts) over a period of time - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, statistics, postgresql-9.6

I have a high transactional Postgres 9.6 database and wanted to see if how to check the number of Updates/inserts/deletes over a period of time (like 30Mins/1 Hour/24Hours) for gathering some DB stats.
I know we can get table level info from pg_stat_user_tables view by running the view once now and once after 1 hours/24hours (depending on the required time range). But I am not sure how to get these stats at a DB level.
Can someone please suggest a good way to check the same?

Thanks

Comment: Thats what I was thinking.. but was looking for other DB level options (if available)

Comment: Got it. The table level sum up helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to sum up the table statistics for all tables in the database, as there are no such statistics collected on the database level.